# what is the observer name of savepayment in magento

Tags: magento

i want the name of savepayment observer can any body please answer me i have searched on the

google but not lucky yet.. please reply.

the savepayment  means the button we click before the place order i mean to say when

we choose the payment method in onepage checkout.

Thanks,
Jitendra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, there simply is no such observer event* in Magento. That's why you cannot find it.

But you can override

```
Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::savePaymentAction()
```

to get in control of saving payment methods.

---

*<sub>At least not in Magento CE 1.3 - 1.5. Don't know if this is also true for Magento PE/EE</sub>

Answer (score 1):

perhaps controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_savePayment might help you ?